# SQL-Azure Database Units

Tags: azure

can someone help me to understand how those database units are being calculated? I have one database server with 5 databases. Each day I get charged about 0.06 DU - how do I figure out where this number is coming from?

I have a MSDN-subscription with 1 DU per month included. I though, that would mean I have one DB instance per month available. With a rate of 0.06 DU per day I will use up 2 DU per month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a Professional or Premium MSDN Subscription you are entitled to using 1 DU (Database Unit):

> This offer enables customers to utilize $9.99 of Web Edition database
>   per month at our standard Pay-As-You-Go rates. This equates to one, **1
>   GB** Web Edition database or **two, 100 MB** Web Edition databases per
>   month.

So could it be that your database is larger than 1GB? Or are you using more than two 100 MB databases?

You can find more information on the pricing page under [Data Management](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/).

Comment: Nope, I have 4 databases with about 1MB in size; and the master-database with 2MB. That's all. I would have thought, that my subscription would cover that :(

Comment: 4 databases is too much (the smallest database size is 100MB, even if you're using less). You'll need to remove 2 databases if you want your subscription to cover it.

Comment: I was afraid you would say something like this ... :( but my current app-design request isolated databases. But thx.

Comment: Why not use different schemas?

Comment: because I want to build a multi-tenancy application. So I plan for one database per tenant to get a isolation of tenants. I also have one master database to hold tenant data. Currently I have to two azure instance, one for dev and one for testing/presentation.

Comment: @nyn3x Long time since this question was posted, but one-database-per-tenant is in general less ideal than one-schema-per-tenant.